# Examples of reduced associative algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

An associative $K$-algebra A is called reduced (or often basic) if $A/rad(A)$ has no nilpotent elements. It can be shown that this is equivalent to that $A/rad(A)$ is a isomorphic to a direct sum of division algebras. Here $rad(A)$ is the Jacobson radical of $A$.

In the article "Reduced group algebras" and a related one (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819466/the-division-algebras-arising-in-the-wedderburn-decomposition-of-a-finite-group) in $char(K)=p>0$ it is shown that for group algebras reduced=soluble holds. (An associatve algebra is called soluble if the factor $A/rad(A)$ is commutative.)

If we take a soluble associative algebra and the direct sum with a division algebra (e.g. lower diagonal matices togehther with real quaternion) we obtain an example of that kind.

My question is whether there are some natural examples of such reduced associative algebras which are not soluble and arising from direct products of division algebras, soluble (or abelian) algebras.

Is it possible to obtain a reduced algebra from every associative algebra?

One source is local algebras and their direct sum. But not all reduced algebras are a direct sum of local algebras.

Comment: Do you assume that your algebras are finite-dimensional? And what do you mean by a soluble algebra?

Comment: Oh, and it's cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908449/examples-of-reduced-associative-algebras

Comment: One more thing: if you refer to some article, you should give a complete reference, not just the title...

Comment: For groups, I think you need to be more careful with reduced=solvable.  You need that the quotient by the largest normal $p$-subgroup is an abelian group of order prime to $p$.

Comment: @Tom: I included the definition of soluble associative algebra and the link for $char(K)=p$.

Comment: @Benjamin: Yes, thats true for Lie-solublae group algebras. The groups are classified as you mention it. What I mean is soluble as associative algebra, and as there are only fields in the wedderburn-decomposition in the modular case (as you prooved) the modular group algebra is basic iff it is soluble. In addition, for $char(K)\ne 2$ one can you show that Lie-soluble = soluble for associative algebras of finite-dimension.

Comment: It helps to know what you mean by solvable.

Comment: I guess you can get an example by starting with a group which has a Quaternion division algebra over the rationals as the endomorphism algebra of a simple and tweak it into a monoid to get a nontrivial radical.

Comment: What do you understand by "tweak it into a moniod"?

Comment: Anyway, you can get a reduced algebra from any finite dimensional associative algebra $A$ by taking $eAe$ where $e$ is the sum of primitive orthogonal idempotents one per isomorphism class of projective indecomposables.

Comment: In this algebra then all division algebras occur which are in the Wedderburn-Decomposition of the underlaying algebra $A$. maybe this is the reason why such algebras are called basic?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q$ be the quaternion group of order $8$ and let $P(Q)$ be the power set of $Q$ viewed as a monoid by $AB=\{ab\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$.  Let $\mathbb QP(Q)$ be the contracted monoid algebra of $P(Q)$ over $\mathbb Q$ (so identify the zero of the monoid with the zero of the algebra).  I claim that $\mathbb QP(Q)$ is reduced but not solvable.

The algebra $\mathbb QP(Q)$ is not semisimple because $P(Q)$ contains elements which are not von Neumann regular.  Its semisimple quotient is the direct product $\prod_{H\leq Q} \mathbb Q[Q/H]$ of the group algebras of the quotients of $Q$.  Since it is well known that $\mathbb QQ$ has a quaternion Wedderburn component, and the other direct factors are commutative this is an example of a reduced algebra which is not semisimple.

There might be a clever argument to show it is a direct product of a quaternion division algebra and a soluble algebra using Mobius inversion on the subgroup lattice.  I will have to think about it.

Comment: Thanks for this example. Since we have zero characteristics there is also an complemen by the Wedderburn-Malcev-Theorem. Do you know such a complement? Are this the algebras you mentioned in your previous answer?

Comment: I know the complement. If I have a chance later I will write something.

Comment: The semisimple quotient is the subalgebra spanned by the cosets of subgroups.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I guess there is already some theory in place for such algebras? The background of my example is that I am looking for the Cartan-Subalgebras of the associated Lie-algebra. In this case one has to determine the maximal commutative subalgebras of the complement and then calculating the centralizer of these in the whole algebra.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2009-361-03/S0002-9947-08-04712-0/ will tell you which monooids have reduced algebras.  You can also see from there and group theory which ones are not solvable.  I am not sure how easy it is to see whether it is a direct product of division algebras and solvable algebras.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I will study these kind of monoid algebras.

Comment: Do you know a description of the Jacobson radical for $KP(G)$?

Comment: I know a basis.

Comment: That would be fine because I need to calculate the centralizer of a maximal torus of the complement within the Jacobson radical.

Comment: Additional question: Besides the theory you gave me the link to the article is there any kind of theory developed explicitly for this specific power set monoid algebra of a group/monoid?

Comment: For the power set of a group I know a bit more than what is in the paper but it is not written. For general power sets of monoids things are more complicated.

Comment: Okay, maybe its an interesting associative algebra to study. Can you explain me how to get a basis for the Jacobson Radical in the case of a group, please?